# Index of element in an array in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to display indices of an array in a for loop in Pyrhon.

Here is my code:

```
computerPlayersList = [nbr]
For computerPlayer in computerPlayersList:
     print(computerPlayersList.index(computerPlayer))
```

But this is not working ? What's the correct displaying method please ? Thank you

Comment: In future question posts please define "not working". Use [`enumerate`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html).

Comment: Change `For` → `for`!

Answer (score 0):

In python, keywords must be written in lowercase. Use `for`, not `For`:

```
computerPlayersList = [5, 3, 9, 6]
for computerPlayer in computerPlayersList:
     print(computerPlayersList.index(computerPlayer))
```

returns

```
0
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `enumerate()` method for index and the value in the following manner:

```python
for index,computerPlayer in enumerate(computerPlayersList):
   print (index,computerPlayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code** :

```
computerPlayersList = [10,20,30]
for counter,computerPlayer in enumerate(computerPlayersList):
     print(counter,computerPlayer)
```

using **enumerate** is also a great option. the *counter* variable will be having the index value of each item.

**Output** :

```
0 10
1 20
2 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly "For" lower case since it's a keyword.

```
    computerPlayersList = ["nbr","abc"]
    for computerPlayer in computerPlayersList:
          print(computerPlayersList.index(computerPlayer))
```

or

```
     computerPlayersList = [10,20,30]
    for computerPlayer in computerPlayersList:
          print(computerPlayersList.index(computerPlayer))
```

The elements in the list are either string or integer/float so list cannot have variable names.

```
    >>> a=10
    >>> b=[]
    >>> c=b[a]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm guessing that you are giving variable names inside the list.

So there are two errors, next time post that error message so that we can see what exactly is the problem.